# PHP Obtain the URL as a variable

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have noticed that many websites use urls that end in

```
website.com/index.php?var="value"&var2="value2"
```

and I was wondering how I could make it so that instead of having that be the end of the URL have this instead:

```
website.com/value/value2
```

and then have it so that instead of searching for "/value/value2" inside of the servers root folder it would instead just open *index.php* and then inside the *PHP* coding have a function that would get what the *URL* is. Either as a string "/value/value2" or an array "value" "value2" it doesn't matter but just some way of getting those variables. This would be so that the *URL* could be cleaned up and easy to tell where you were in the website.

Also if there is a way of doing this would it be possible for *style.php* that is in the same folder as *index.php* (but has a *PHP header* setting it to output *CSS*) that would be called in the head of *index.php* using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" url="style.php" />` or whatever the syntax for that is, to be able to obtain that same variable so that the *css* styling could be changed according to the *URL*.

Comment: Search for seo friendly urls and/or .htaccess url rewriting

Comment: and mod_rewrite (assuming apache), then php's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or similar from: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rewriting of urls in .htaccess file

Check this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?var=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

There are three parts to this:

1. RewriteRule specifies that this is a rule for rewriting (as opposed to a condition or some other directive). The command is to rewrite part 2 into part 3.
2. This part is a regex, and the rule will be run only if the URL matches this regex. In this case, it says - look for the beginning of the string, then a bunch of non-slash characters, then a slash, then another bunch of non-slash characters. then again bunch of non-slash characters, then a slash, then another bunch of non-slash characters. The parentheses mean the parts within the parentheses will be stored for future reference.
3. Finally, this part says to rewrite the given URL in this format. $1 and $2 refer to the parts that were captured and stored.

Refer [Beginner's Guide to mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).
Also [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) for same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re write the URL.. if u are using apache you would have to add changes in the `.htaccess` file. Check [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and this [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

If using apache, enable mod_rewrite and use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

If using nginx, use nginx_rewrite_module http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

And inside your index.php parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable, it will contain requested url.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily. Everything after the question mark are called $_GET variables. So you can call $_GET['var'] or $_GET['var2'] to get their values.

For example. I have the URL: http://www.example.com?username=username&password=password

Now i can take that url and make it so:

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];
$newUrl = 'http://www.example.com/' . $user . '/' . $pass;
echo '<a href="' . $newUrl . '">Link text here</a>';
?>
```

This results in a formatted url based on $_GET variables: http://www.example.com/username/password

Comment: Honestly, that is the easiest way. You already have the url root, and the $_GET array, so why not use what you have instead of making a pointless regexp. It is your choice to use my answer or not, but I do this for a living and this is what i would do.

Comment: where would <a href="$newUrl"> lead u to.? will there be such a page.?

Comment: i updated my post to reflect what you are asking. The echo will create: <a href="www.example.com/username/password">Link text here</a>

Comment: where does this link(www.example.com/username/password) take the page to.?

Comment: If you look at the question, you will see what he is asking. Which is taking $_GET vars and changing them to directories. wither it be from a header('Location: ...') or a link.

Comment: Sorry if my question was ambiguous but what I was actually asking is how to get variables from the URL not send variables to the URL...